# systemctl set-property assignment parameters

Tags: systemd

I want to edit the properties of a system service using systemctl.

For example, I want to change the properties of `FailureAction=none` on a service that failed, but I don't know what parameters are valid.

I looked at these...

- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.directives.html
- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#DisableControllers=

...but I don't find them helpful, at all.

Are there more detailed references, that can help me with using valid parameters... and, or does anyone know the acceptable parameters for `DisableControllers=`, and `FailureAction=` ?

Comment: Why don't you fix the reason that the service failed?

Comment: I checked for a fix, but did not find any. It is a Firmware issue, so I think the system I am using is not up to par. It's a 32 bit, system with a number of hardware issues. See https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/update-computer-firmware-in-linux/   Since the service does not start, I am helpless... it seems.

Comment: What service? What firmware? What error message? What hardware issues? You have to give us more details to work with.

Comment: The service mentioned in the link https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/update-computer-firmware-in-linux/ fwupd.service

Comment: I did not mention an error message. My question does not involve fixing the hardware or software issue, but finding information to help me change properties in systemd.

Comment: This is an XY problem. You're asking how to ignore the error in a system service. This is wrong. Either fix the system service or stop using it.

Comment: I have no choice but to ignore this issue. 
fwupd is still heavily in development. As of 2015, the functionality 
it provides is not yet available on most systems. - Daniel Jared Dominguez 
The pre-installed package does not work on my system, as it does on others, who can upgrade, or use a newer installation, or system. 
https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/fwupd-service-fails-to-start/922/9
https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?321090-fwupd-error-in-software-center&p=1821524#post1821524

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered how to productively navigate the man pages, and found what I was looking for.
[FailureAction](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.unit.5.html)
[DisableControllers](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.resource-control.5.html)